# Move bounty deadline

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes I would like to add a bounty to a question (usually not even my own question) however I know that I won't be available in exactly 7 days to accept the correct answer. Once, I even had something come up and I had to give my login info to a colleague to accept what was in his opinion the best answer. Life sucks, sometimes we cannot help but miss a deadline.

In my opinion there should be a one-time "extend bounty time" option available to a question. This option could even expire 24 / 48 hours before the bounty itself expires, or cost the asker an additional points penalty (perhaps add half this penalty to the bounty itself). Here are some supporting arguments in favour:

- [Asker too busy to get to answer in time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73353/when-to-accept-answers-for-bounty-question)
- [Asker did not return in time and answerer got no bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24663/allow-lapsed-bounty-questions-to-be-accepted)

Be there no mistake, I feel that deadlines on bounty questions are very important and I agree that they are necessary and should be enforced in general. However, if intelligent methods to prevent abuse can be determined, then an option to move the deadline would be a big help to both asker and answerer.

**Amendum:** [Considering the new grace-period feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49830/option-to-extend-bounties-by-24-hours), I now longer see the need to move a bounty deadline to be as urgent as it was before. I think that the 24 grace period is a terrific solution to the issue for most common cases that I could conjecture. However, there are a few fringe cases where an extension would help so I'll not close this thread.

Comment: The grace period is over a year old...

Comment: I've never noticed it, so I've always rushed to award bounty. I do have an open bounty now, so I will review the information made available to me as the bounty giver (it is not my question) and I'll make suggestions to improve the way that information is made available. Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you miss the deadline and feel responsible to grant rep to the best answer, you can always post a second bounty targeted at that answer. You miss the deadline, you pay the late fee. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

This would add more complication than is good IMO. A fixed time frame that never changes is fair to everyone, including those who work to answer the question.

There already is a (relatively new) feature that gives you [24 hours' time to choose the bounty winner after the bounty has expired.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49830/option-to-extend-bounties-by-24-hours) (Maybe extending that time to 48 hours would be an option instead?)

Comment: Thanks. I agree that that new grace period will certainly help.